# How to transform RedirectMatch to RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Could you help me please to transform this functions to "RewriteRule" format?

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/auth/(.*) http://1.1.10.7/auth/$1`

I need to change from this format because this cause a redirect loop and I want to add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=1.1.10.7`.

I tried this, but isn't works :

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=1.1.10.7
RewriteRule ^kubota-store-admin$ http://10.1.1.36/kubota-store-admin/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]`

The results I need are:

- http://example.com/ => http://example.com/
- http://example.com/test/ =>  http://example.com/test/
- http://example.com/auth/ => http://1.1.10.7/auth/
- http://example.com/auth/login => http://1.1.10.7/auth/login
- http://example.com/auth/forget_password => http://1.1.10.7/auth/forget_password

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the http_host string is "example.com" and it should not match the destination host

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^auth/(.*)$ http://1.1.10.7/auth/$1 [L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, can I use this format? To process http_host other than come from 1.1.10.7.  
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^1.1.10.7$`

Comment: Yes you can use a negitive RewriteCond that excludes the destination domain.